# Is it possible to launch a node on another computer from my computer?

Tags: ros, communication, rosnode, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a mobile robot project. I have tested the teleoperation by launching all nodes on the Pi, including the master, the keystroke detector, and finally the node that sends commands to the motors. I have also established a connection between the main computer I'm using and the PI. While I can run almost all nodes on the laptop, the node that sends commands to the motors requires the RPi.GPIO library, which cannot be run from my laptop. I wanted to know if it is possible to just launch that specific node on the Pi from the convenience of my laptop.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264304/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-node-on-another-computer-from-my-computer?/) by [russ0](https://answers.ros.org/users/30806/russ0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can remotely roslaunch processes. You should use the `machine` tag. http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine

There's a tutorial with some tips here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3